# SQL Server 2005 - WHERE Clause - Use IF or CASE or BOOLEAN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've researched this scenario for a few hours now but cannot seem to find anything that addresses it directly.

I have lots of optional parameters passed into a stored proc. I want to return a recordset that is filtered by none, one or more of the optional params passed into the stored proc.

I'm trying to produce a single query to do this.

Here's my pseudo code (SQL Server 2005):

```
declare @a varchar(10); set @a = null;
declare @b varchar(10); set @b = 'comm%';

select * from x
where (if @a is not null then col1 like @a)
and (if @b is not null then col2 like @b)
```

As you can see I only want to filter on col1 *if* my param (@a) has data. Likewise I only want to filter on col2 *if* my param (@b) has data. If @a and @b are both NULL then the query should return all rows.

I've found several threads that come close to what I want, but none of them address using the LIKE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE (@a IS NULL OR col1 LIKE @a) AND (@b IS NULL OR col2 LIKE @b)
```

Answer (score 4):

You were close - use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM X x
 WHERE (@a IS NULL OR x.col1 LIKE @a)
   AND (@b IS NULL OR x.col2 LIKE @b)
```

But this is [not recommended because it's not sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).  [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) would be a better approach:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT x.*
                   FROM X x
                  WHERE 1 = 1 '

    SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE
                        WHEN @a IS NULL THEN ' ' 
                        ELSE ' AND x.col1 LIKE @a '
                      END 

    SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE
                        WHEN @b IS NULL THEN ' ' 
                        ELSE ' AND x.col2 LIKE @b '
                      END 

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, 
                     N'@a VARCHAR(10), @b VARCHAR(10)',
                     @a, @b

END
```

Comment: Some of my cols will be indexed, while others won't. Flexibility is more important that query execution, so sargability doesn't really factor into my usp. But thanks for your feedback - I'm sure it'll shed light for others on this topic :)

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be the most efficient way to do what you're looking for.  Filtering will only occur on a column if the value passed to the stored procedure is not `NULL`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc_example
@Col1 varchar(30) = NULL,
@Col2 varchar(30) = NULL,
@Col3 varchar(30) = NULL
AS
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col3
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 LIKE COALESCE(@Col1,Col1) AND
      Col2 LIKE COALESCE(@Col2,Col2) AND
      Col3 LIKE COALESCE(@Col3,Col3)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Your solution is also ideal and works for me also.

Comment: This solution is only appropriate if your columns do not allow NULLs.  Otherwise it will not return the correct data.